# Best way to sort a DropDownList in MVC3 / Razor using helper method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu

Hi so I'm pretty new to MVC3 and Razor and I've been trying to get my head around it the past few days. I've been given a task by my project architect to create a helper method that sorts a drop down list in an MVC View. I have a View that retrieves various data from a Controller and I'm returning some values that I want to appear in a drop down list. I've been told not to sort it in the Controller and also to pass the field that we want to sort by into the helper method. I could do it like below but the architect wants to keep the view free of c sharp code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StudyName, new SelectList(ViewBag.StudyTypes, "Value", "Text").OrderBy(l => l.Text))
```

So I've created some sample code and some extension methods to try and get it to work. My idea is to replicate the existing Html.DropDownList method and allow the passing of 'object htmlAttributes' so I can set the style as part of the method call.

Here's my code so far. I'm returning the data for the drop down in ViewBag.StudyTypes in the Edit Controller method:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> mySelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    IList<SelectListItem> myList = new List<SelectListItem>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        myList.Add(new SelectListItem() 
            { Value = i.ToString(), Text = "My Item " + i.ToString(), Selected = i == 2 }
        );
    }

    mySelectList = myList;
    ViewBag.StudyTypes = mySelectList;

    StudyDefinition studydefinition = db.StudyDefinitions.Find(id);

    return View(studydefinition);
}
```

Here's my View code:

```
    @model MyStudyWeb.Models.StudyDefinition

@using MyStudyWeb.Helpers

@{
    ViewBag.Mode = "Edit";
}
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListSorted(new SelectList(ViewBag.StudyTypes, "Value", "Text"))<br />
    @Html.DropDownListSorted("MyList", new SelectList(ViewBag.StudyTypes, "Value", "Text"))<br />
</div>
```

Finally below are the extension methods I'm trying to get to work. The first extension method does nothing, I just get a blank space at that point in the View. The second method kind of works but it's ugly. For the 3rd method I don't know how to specify an 'order by' parameter as the OrderBy on an IEnumerable expects a Linq expression.

```
namespace StudyDefinition.Helpers
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        // 1st sort method: sort the passed in list and return a new sorted list
        public static SelectList DropDownListSorted(this HtmlHelper helper, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList)
        {
            var x = new SelectList(selectList.ToList()).OrderBy(l => l.Text);

            return x as SelectList;
        }

        // 2nd sort method: return IHtml string and create <select> list manually
        public static IHtmlString DropDownListSorted(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, SelectList selectList)
        {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            (selectList).OrderBy(l => l.Text);

            output.Append("<select id=" + name + " name=" + name + ">");

            foreach (var item in selectList)
            {
                output.Append("<option value=" + item.Value.ToString() + ">" + item.Text + "</option>");
            }

            output.Append("</select>");

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(output.ToString());
        }

        // 3rd sort method: pass in order by parameter - how do I use this?
        public static IHtmlString DropDownListSorted(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, SelectList selectList, string orderBy)
        {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

            //How do I use the orderBy parameter?
            (selectList).OrderBy(l => l.Text);

            output.Append("<select id=" + name + " name=" + name + ">");

            foreach (var item in selectList)
            {
                output.Append("<option value=" + item.Value.ToString() + ">" + item.Text + "</option>");
            }

            output.Append("</select>");

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(output.ToString());
        }        
    }
}
```

I really don't know the best approach to take, there may be a much simpler way that I'm totally missing and I might be at the point where I can't see the wood for the trees anymore. Some questions

- Should I return a SelectList or an MvcHtmlString, or something else entirely?
- For the first extension method how do I get the returned SelectList to render in the View?
- How to I pass in a parameter to my extension methods that specifies the sort order?
- How do I pass an 'object htmlAttributes' parameter, and how do I apply this object / parameter to the SelectList?

If anyone has some ideas or suggestions then I'd appreciate some feedback :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first and **most important** part of your code would be to get rid of any `ViewBag/ViewData` (which I personally consider as cancer for MVC applications) and use view models and strongly typed views.

So let's start by defining a view model which would represent the data our view will be working with (a dropdownlistg in this example):

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

then we could have a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            // I am explicitly putting some items out of order
            Items = new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "5", Text = "Item 5" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Item 1" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Item 3" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "Item 4" },
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and a view:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DropDownListForSorted(
    x => x.SelectedItem, 
    Model.Items, 
    new { @class = "foo" }
)
```

and finally the last piece is the helper method which will sort the dropdown by value (you could adapt it to sort by text):

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString DropDownListForSorted<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items, 
        object htmlAttributes
    )
    {
        var model = helper.ViewData.Model;
        var orderedItems = items.OrderBy(x => x.Value);
        return helper.DropDownListFor(
            expression, 
            new SelectList(orderedItems, "Value", "Text"), 
            htmlAttributes
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Darin that's great thanks. A couple of issues though, I'm working on an existing system and all the views have multiple drop down lists, and they are all returned from their Controllers as ViewBag properties. So I can't really change this approach. Secondly the View is already doing 'return View(studydefinition)' which is the Entity class. Is there another way I can return a view model? Thirdly when I add your extension method the DropDownListFor method isn't recognised, I'm getting: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'DropDownListFor'

Comment: @Ciaran Bruen, OK for the existing system and ViewBag. I just mentioned it for future code, to avoid this bad practice. If you have multiple dropdownlists, you would simply have multiple `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` properties on your view model. Concerning the `return View(studydefinition)`, that's the correct way to pass view models to views. Thirdly, the `DropDownListFor` extension method is defined in the `System.Web.Mvc.Html` namespace, so simply add a using to this namespace at the top of the file containing the `DropDownListForSorted` helper in order to bring it into scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a database you can use a query to define the sort element

```
using (BDMMContext dataContext = new BDMMContext())
{
foreach (Arquiteto arq in dataContext.Arquitetos.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM  Arquitetos ORDER BY Nome"))
                    {
                        SelectListItem selectItem = new SelectListItem { Text = arq.Nome, Value = arq.Arquiteto_Id.ToString() };
                        //
                        list.Add(selectItem);
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add in the sorting before you return the items to the dropdown list.

Do this:

**Models: StudyViewModel.cs**

```
public class StudyViewModel {
    public string StudyName { get; set; }
    public string StudyTypes { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:  StudyController.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
public class StudyController 
{
    public List<SelectListItem> studyTypes() 
    {
        List<SelectListItem> itemList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        for (var i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            itemList.Add = new SelectListItem({
                Value = i.ToString();
                Text = "My Item";
            });
        }
        // You can sort here....
        List<SelectListItem> sortedList = itemList.OrderBy(x=>x.Text);
        return sortedList;
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        //You won't need this because you get it using your
        //controller's routine, instead 
        //ViewBag.StudyTypes = studySlots.OrderBy(e => e.Value);

        //-- unless you need to add these values to the model for 
        // some reason (outside of filling the ddl), in which case....
        // StudyViewModel svm = new StudyViewModel();
        // svm.StudyTypes = studySlots.OrderBy(e => e.Value);
        // svm.StudyName = "My Item";
        // return View(svm);

        // Otherwise, just....
        return View();
    }
}
```

**View: Edit.cshtml**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StudyName)
    .OptionLabel('Select...')
    .DataTextField('Text')
    .DataValueField('Value')
    .Datasource(source => 
    {
       // This is where you populate your data from the controller
        source.Read(read => 
        {
            read.Action("studyTypes", "Study");
        });
    })
    .Value(Model.StudyName != null ? Model.StudyName.ToString() : "")
)
```

This way will avoid ViewBags and just use a function to fill in the values, directly.